# Facebook method isSessionValid() always returns false in Android

Tags: android, facebook

**Code:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                if(fb.isSessionValid())
                {
                    Log.i("Checking isSessionValid()","Inside isSessionValid()");
                    try {
                        fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                        updatebuttonimage();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.i("","Jumped isSessionValid");
                    fb.authorize(MainActivity.this,new String[]{"email"},new DialogListener() {


                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"FacebookError",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
.....
```

When i am trying to check for isSessionValid(), it always returns false and it doesn't enter the method.I have also tried adding the following code in onCreate() but it prints the same KeyHash in my logcat so no use :

```
 try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.example.facebook_integration", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Help will be much appreciated guys. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the key hash was the problem and re-generating it again solved my issue.

**NOTE :**
KeyHash is separate for each emulator or device i believe cause i have initially generated an KeyHash for my emulator and later started working on a real-time device and so i had to generate the hash key again to make it work. isSessionValid() has returned true only after generating another KeyHash for the current running android device(Not sure if that was really causing the issue). But can give it a try for what its worth. Hope this is useful.